# How to replace parts of a sentence with array of strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, replace, find

I have this sentence:

```
span class="searchmatch" Program /span, programme, programmer, or span class="searchmatch" programming /span may refer to: span class="searchmatch" Program /span management, the process of managing several related projects Time management Program
```

I want to remove all the tags so it will be like:

```
Program, programme, programmer, or programming may refer to:  management, the process of managing several related projects Time management Program.
```

so I split the sentence into array like this:
`const arrayContent = result.snippet.split(' ');`

and made a array of the words i want to remove like this:
`const removedText = ['span class="searchmatch"', '/span'];`

Is there a function that receives two arrays (just like arrayContent and removedText), search if in the first array there is a string that match to a string in the second array and if so, replace it with an empty string?

Comment: Are the <> missing from your text? I did not see them while I edited it

Comment: Yes i removed them because with the <> the all tag disapear

Comment: Just to clarify epascarello's question, do you really have just a string? or are you getting this from the DOM? If you're querying the DOM you can simply use `.innerText` on the parent element.

Comment: Well it makes no sense to use reg exp to alter the HTML, simple DOM remove() would clean it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have used regex like this :

```js
const toRemove = ['span class="searchmatch"', '/span'];

// create regex like "a|b|c|..." according to what the array contains
const regex = new RegExp(toRemove.join("|"), 'gi');

const oldString = `span class="searchmatch" Program /span, programme, programmer, or span class="searchmatch" programming /span may refer to: span class="searchmatch" Program /span management, the process of managing several related projects Time management Program`

const newString = oldString.replaceAll(regex, '');

console.log(newString);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about such function:

```
const removeStrings: string = (text: string, array: string[]) => {
    let resultText = Object.assign({}, text);

    array.forEach(item => {
        if (resultText.includes(item)) {
            resultText = resultText.replaceAll(item, '');
        }
    });

    return resultText;
}
```

Alternatively for two arrays:

```
const removeStrings: string[] = (array1: string[], array2: string[]) => {
    let resultArr = Object.assign({}, array1);

    resultArr = resultArr.map(item1 =>
        array.forEach(item => {
            if (item1 === item)) {
                return '';
            }
        });

        return item1;
    });

    return resultArr;
}
```